# Javascript multiple search new position variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, position, match

I have the following text:

```
var text= 
    "The sad sad man uses a bat to swing the bats 
    away from his sad garden .
    Sadly he doesn't succeed. "
```

Let's say i want to search for the word `"sad"`.

```
var match;
re = /sad/g,
    match;
while (match = re.exec(text)) {
    console.log(match); 
match.poz = ....
}
```

How can i make `match.poz` to be a tuple(array) like this `[line,position on the collumn]` all starting from 0,0 ?

Eg.

- 1 match --> match.poz = [0,4]
- 2 match --> match.poz =  [0,8]
- 3 match --> match.poz =  [1,14]
- 4 match --> match.poz =  [2,0]

Comment: how i can make match.poz like one in the list.. sorry for being so innacurate

Comment: Are you wanting to find the last match in your text string?

Comment: no i want to add to match , match.poz that has [the line where is the search, position on column]

Comment: Something along this line? http://jsfiddle.net/Zx5CK/1/ Note, have your JS console open.

Comment: yes. perfect! you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build a simple parser, instead of using a regex, which I don't think is possible (without a lot of help) to get the position in Javascript. All this does is go through the line, one character at a time, and "peek" ahead to see if the current position gives either `sad` or `\n`.

```
var text = "The sad sad man uses a bat to swing the bats \naway from his sad garden .\nSadly he doesn't succeed.",
    length = text.length,
    matches = [],
    lines = 0,
    pos = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    var word = text.substring(i, i + 3).toLowerCase();

    if (word == 'sad') {
        matches[matches.length] = [lines, pos];
    }

    if (word.indexOf('\n') == 0) {
        lines++;
        pos = 0;
    } else {
        pos++;
    }
}

console.log(matches);
```

Which gives me the following in Firebug console:

```
[[0, 4], [0, 8], [1, 14], [2, 0]]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zx5CK/1/

Answer (score 0):

First i think you need to be able to delimit the lines in some way. Probably using some character(like '\n' for example) in the input data.
Then one way to solve the problem is to use the split function to get you the words in each line as an array. You can then  write a function which takes in a line and the required word and compares each word with what you are searching for.

```
 //where i denotes the currently read line.
 var indexInLine = checkforWordInLine(input.line[i].split(' '), "sad");
 if(indexInLine != -1) 
 //word found in line. 
 // save indexInLine and 'i', the line index      


 function checkforWordInLine(line, searchKey)
 {
    var wordIndex = -1;
   for(var i=0,j=line.length; i < j; i++)
   {
      if(line[i] === searchKey)
      wordIndex = i;
   }
   return wordIndex;
 }
```